# lambda capture, capturing an "undeclared variable"

Tags: c++, lambda, closures, language-lawyer

I was surprised by a snippet in [this C++ weekly](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YxSg_Gzm-VQ).
I reproduced here the part that I don't understand:

```cpp
int main() {
    auto accumulator = [sum = 0](int value) mutable {
        sum += value;
        return sum;
    };
    accumulator(1);          // expected return value: 1
    accumulator(2);          // expected return value: 1+2
    return accumulator(-1);  // expected return value: 1+2-1
}
```

The implicit expectation (in comment) is fulfilled but I don't recognize this capture syntax: sum does not exist in the lambda declaration scope, so it cannot capture that.
I know about this kind of syntax: `[lhs = rhs](whatever){whatever_again};` that declares a `lhs` variable in the closure that is initialized by `rhs` value from the declaring scope, at the time of declaration.
The fact that this code is working seems to mean that:

- if the requested capture variable is not declared, then the capture is actually a definition;
- the persistence of the value between calls, implies that `sum` is actually a member of the lambda closure;
- `sum` is not const because the lambda is mutable.

Yet I cannot match these hypothesis with lambda cppreference.

I know about this kind of syntax: `[lhs = rhs](whatever){whatever_again};` that declares a `lhs` variable in the closure that is initialized by `rhs` value from the declaring scope, at the time of declaration.
The above behavior seems to indicate that `rhs` can be merely a value, and that the actual type of `lhs` is automatically deduced (I think that I get this point right from [ClosureType::Captures](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#:%7E:text=ClosureType%3A%3ACaptures), reproduced below).
**Is my understanding correct? And can someone point a reference or explain the cppreference wording?**
I'm afraid that it rises a second question which is probably a duplicate (fill free to tell so or to ask me to split the post in 2): **how is determined the type of the variables, inside the lambda body?**

##### Notes

from ClosureType::Captures: type inside lambda body.

> The type of each data member is the type of the corresponding captured entity, except if the entity has reference type (in that case, references to functions are captured as lvalue references to the referenced functions, and references to objects are captured as copies of the referenced objects).

also from ClosureType::Captures: closure non-static member variable:

> the closure type includes unnamed non-static data members, declared in unspecified order, that hold copies of all entities that were so captured.

IMHO, if I extend the *entity* notion from `lvalue` to any kind of values, my hypothesis could be correct.

Comment: There isn't anywhere written that `rhs` *must* be a variable, is it? So yes, your understanding is correct. The reference wording: Imagine `int n = ...; int& m = n; [m](){};` – how would you now expect `m` to be captured? By reference because `m` is a reference??? Of course not, we'd capture `n` by copy, conforming to user expectation when not seeing the declaration of `m`, and that's what the paragraph mandates, too.

Comment: @RichardCritten Thanks, may be it is a vocabulary misunderstanding on my side. I considered that the capture was the whole expression between squared brackets. Is actually each comma separated expression between the brackets called a _capture_? Thus, in the question example, `sum` would be a capture?

Comment: At least that's what matches the wording at [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (note them speaking of capture**s** and a capture list)…

Comment: As if the lambda were... `struct accumulator_t { int sum{ 0 }; int operator()(int value) { sum += value; return sum; } };`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The implicit expectation (in comment) is fulfilled but I don't recognize this capture syntax: `sum` does not exist in the lambda declaration scope, so it cannot capture that.

`sum` doesn't have to. `sum` is not the name of the entity we are capturing, it is just a name in the capture clause that is an alias for a data member of the lambda, and which we can use in the call operator. Only when `sum` has no initializer is `sum` also the name of the captured entity.
This feature (capture clause with initializers) is called *Generalized Captures*.

The above code snippet will make a lot more sense if we translate it into what happens "under the hood":

```cpp
int main() {
    // exposition-only, closure type is unnamed.
    struct __lambda {
        // exposition-only, data member is nameless.
        // lambda is mutable, so member is not const.
        int __sum;
        
        // return type will deduce to int.
        // mutable lambda means our call operator is not const-qualified.
        // call operator is automatically constexpr because it can be.
        constexpr auto operator()(int value) {
            __sum += value;
            return __sum;
        }
    };

    // We've used copy initialization in our capture, so copy initialization
    // must take place for the __sum member.
    // However, closure types are not aggregate types.
    auto accumulator = __lambda{.__sum = 0};
    accumulator(1);
    accumulator(2);
    return accumulator(-1);
}
```

You can see that `[sum = 0]` in our capture clause simply means that we have a member of type `int` in the closure type.

> The type of each data member is the type of the corresponding captured entity, except if the entity has reference type.

- See [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#:%7E:text=ClosureType%3A%3ACaptures)

In this case, the captured entity is the temporary object `0`, which is of type `int`, so our data member is also of type `int`.

---

See also: [Your code on cppinsights.io](https://cppinsights.io/s/b85f7fe1)